# Pipenv could not resolve dependencies, seemingly without indicating which dependencies couldn't be resolved

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv, pipenv-install

I'm trying to install the dependencies for a project that's working on a colleague's machine.

The Pipfile looks like:

**Pipfile**

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
aio-pika = "==7.2.0"
aiohttp = "==3.8.1"
aiormq = "==6.2.3"
aiosignal = "==1.2.0"
async-timeout = "==4.0.2"
attrs = "==21.4.0"
beautifulsoup4 = "==4.11.1"
bokeh = "==2.4.2"
bs4 = "==0.0.1"
charset-normalizer = "==2.0.12"
click = "==8.1.3"
cycler = "==0.11.0"
et-xmlfile = "==1.1.0"
fonttools = "==4.33.3"
frozenlist = "==1.3.0"
idna = "==3.3"
jinja2 = "==3.1.2"
joblib = "==1.1.0"
kiwisolver = "==1.4.2"
markupsafe = "==2.1.1"
matplotlib = "==3.5.2"
motor = "==3.0.0"
multidict = "==6.0.2"
nltk = "==3.7"
numpy = "==1.22.3"
openpyxl = "==3.0.10"
pamqp = "==3.1.0"
pandas = "==1.4.2"
pillow = "==9.1.0"
pymongo = "==4.3.3"
pyparsing = "==3.0.8"
python-dateutil = "==2.8.2"
pytz = "==2022.1"
pyyaml = "==6.0"
regex = "==2022.4.24"
scikit-learn = "==1.0.2"
scipy = "==1.8.0"
seaborn = "==0.11.2"
six = "==1.16.0"
sklearn = "==0.0"
soupsieve = "==2.3.2.post1"
threadpoolctl = "==3.1.0"
tornado = "==6.1"
tqdm = "==4.64.0"
typing-extensions = "==4.2.0"
xlsxwriter = "==3.0.3"
yarl = "==1.7.2"
jwt = "*"
argon2-cffi = "*"
requests = "*"


[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "*"
```

I try to install the dependencies with

`pipenv install`

On doing so, I get the following error:

```
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv run pip install <requirement_name> to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the versions actually installed in the virtualenv.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: metadata generation failed
```

The stacktrace doesn't seem to indicate which package failed, and only points to lines from files within pipenv. I can include the entire stacktrace if necessary.

I'm not sure which dependency to try, so I can' do `pipenv run pip install <requirement_name>`, so instead I run `pipenv graph`. Nothing results. So, I try to manually install every package with `pipenv run pip install <all packages>`. That seems to do something. I again run `pipenv graph`

```
aio-pika==9.2.1
├── aiormq [required: >=6.7.7,<6.8.0, installed: 6.7.7]
│   ├── pamqp [required: ==3.2.1, installed: 3.2.1]
│   └── yarl [required: Any, installed: 1.9.2]
│       ├── idna [required: >=2.0, installed: 3.4]
│       └── multidict [required: >=4.0, installed: 6.0.4]
└── yarl [required: Any, installed: 1.9.2]
    ├── idna [required: >=2.0, installed: 3.4]
    └── multidict [required: >=4.0, installed: 6.0.4]
aiohttp==3.8.5
├── aiosignal [required: >=1.1.2, installed: 1.3.1]
│   └── frozenlist [required: >=1.1.0, installed: 1.4.0]
├── async-timeout [required: >=4.0.0a3,<5.0, installed: 4.0.3]
├── attrs [required: >=17.3.0, installed: 23.1.0]
├── charset-normalizer [required: >=2.0,<4.0, installed: 3.2.0]
├── frozenlist [required: >=1.1.1, installed: 1.4.0]
├── multidict [required: >=4.5,<7.0, installed: 6.0.4]
└── yarl [required: >=1.0,<2.0, installed: 1.9.2]
    ├── idna [required: >=2.0, installed: 3.4]
    └── multidict [required: >=4.0, installed: 6.0.4]
argon2-cffi==21.3.0
└── argon2-cffi-bindings [required: Any, installed: 21.2.0]
    └── cffi [required: >=1.0.1, installed: 1.15.1]
        └── pycparser [required: Any, installed: 2.21]
bokeh==3.2.1
├── contourpy [required: >=1, installed: 1.1.0]
│   └── numpy [required: >=1.16, installed: 1.25.2]
├── Jinja2 [required: >=2.9, installed: 3.1.2]
│   └── MarkupSafe [required: >=2.0, installed: 2.1.3]
├── numpy [required: >=1.16, installed: 1.25.2]
├── packaging [required: >=16.8, installed: 23.1]
├── pandas [required: >=1.2, installed: 2.0.3]
│   ├── numpy [required: >=1.21.0, installed: 1.25.2]
│   ├── numpy [required: >=1.23.2, installed: 1.25.2]
│   ├── python-dateutil [required: >=2.8.2, installed: 2.8.2]
│   │   └── six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.16.0]
│   ├── pytz [required: >=2020.1, installed: 2023.3]
│   └── tzdata [required: >=2022.1, installed: 2023.3]
├── pillow [required: >=7.1.0, installed: 10.0.0]
├── PyYAML [required: >=3.10, installed: 6.0.1]
├── tornado [required: >=5.1, installed: 6.3.2]
└── xyzservices [required: >=2021.09.1, installed: 2023.7.0]
bs4==0.0.1
└── beautifulsoup4 [required: Any, installed: 4.12.2]
    └── soupsieve [required: >1.2, installed: 2.4.1]
jwt==1.3.1
└── cryptography [required: >=3.1,!=3.4.0, installed: 41.0.3]
    └── cffi [required: >=1.12, installed: 1.15.1]
        └── pycparser [required: Any, installed: 2.21]
motor==3.2.0
└── pymongo [required: >=4.4,<5, installed: 4.4.1]
    └── dnspython [required: >=1.16.0,<3.0.0, installed: 2.4.2]
nltk==3.8.1
├── click [required: Any, installed: 8.1.6]
├── joblib [required: Any, installed: 1.3.2]
├── regex [required: >=2021.8.3, installed: 2023.8.8]
└── tqdm [required: Any, installed: 4.66.1]
openpyxl==3.1.2
└── et-xmlfile [required: Any, installed: 1.1.0]
requests==2.31.0
├── certifi [required: >=2017.4.17, installed: 2023.7.22]
├── charset-normalizer [required: >=2,<4, installed: 3.2.0]
├── idna [required: >=2.5,<4, installed: 3.4]
└── urllib3 [required: >=1.21.1,<3, installed: 2.0.4]
scikit-learn==1.3.0
├── joblib [required: >=1.1.1, installed: 1.3.2]
├── numpy [required: >=1.17.3, installed: 1.25.2]
├── scipy [required: >=1.5.0, installed: 1.11.1]
│   └── numpy [required: >=1.21.6,<1.28.0, installed: 1.25.2]
└── threadpoolctl [required: >=2.0.0, installed: 3.2.0]
seaborn==0.12.2
├── matplotlib [required: >=3.1,!=3.6.1, installed: 3.7.2]
│   ├── contourpy [required: >=1.0.1, installed: 1.1.0]
│   │   └── numpy [required: >=1.16, installed: 1.25.2]
│   ├── cycler [required: >=0.10, installed: 0.11.0]
│   ├── fonttools [required: >=4.22.0, installed: 4.42.0]
│   ├── kiwisolver [required: >=1.0.1, installed: 1.4.4]
│   ├── numpy [required: >=1.20, installed: 1.25.2]
│   ├── packaging [required: >=20.0, installed: 23.1]
│   ├── pillow [required: >=6.2.0, installed: 10.0.0]
│   ├── pyparsing [required: >=2.3.1,<3.1, installed: 3.0.9]
│   └── python-dateutil [required: >=2.7, installed: 2.8.2]
│       └── six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.16.0]
├── numpy [required: >=1.17,!=1.24.0, installed: 1.25.2]
└── pandas [required: >=0.25, installed: 2.0.3]
    ├── numpy [required: >=1.21.0, installed: 1.25.2]
    ├── numpy [required: >=1.23.2, installed: 1.25.2]
    ├── python-dateutil [required: >=2.8.2, installed: 2.8.2]
    │   └── six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.16.0]
    ├── pytz [required: >=2020.1, installed: 2023.3]
    └── tzdata [required: >=2022.1, installed: 2023.3]
sklearn==0.0.post7
typing-extensions==4.7.1
XlsxWriter==3.1.2
```

I search online for automatic dependency issue checkers for a pipenv graph output, but can't find one, so manually search eat package subdependency for any conflicts. By my eye, there aren't any. Not being entirely clear on what to do next, I try `pipenv lock`, because I believe that should generate a pipenv lockfile based on the actual packages installed in the VM.

I get the same error as before.

I ask my colleague to run `pipenv graph` and send me the output. He does:

```
aio-pika==7.2.0
  - aiormq [required: ~=6.2.3, installed: 6.2.3]
    - pamqp [required: ==3.1.0, installed: 3.1.0]
    - yarl [required: Any, installed: 1.7.2]
      - idna [required: >=2.0, installed: 3.3]
      - multidict [required: >=4.0, installed: 6.0.2]
  - yarl [required: Any, installed: 1.7.2]
    - idna [required: >=2.0, installed: 3.3]
    - multidict [required: >=4.0, installed: 6.0.2]
aiohttp==3.8.1
  - aiosignal [required: >=1.1.2, installed: 1.2.0]
    - frozenlist [required: >=1.1.0, installed: 1.3.0]
  - async-timeout [required: >=4.0.0a3,<5.0, installed: 4.0.2]
  - attrs [required: >=17.3.0, installed: 21.4.0]
  - charset-normalizer [required: >=2.0,<3.0, installed: 2.0.12]
  - frozenlist [required: >=1.1.1, installed: 1.3.0]
  - multidict [required: >=4.5,<7.0, installed: 6.0.2]
  - yarl [required: >=1.0,<2.0, installed: 1.7.2]
    - idna [required: >=2.0, installed: 3.3]
    - multidict [required: >=4.0, installed: 6.0.2]
argon2-cffi==21.3.0
  - argon2-cffi-bindings [required: Any, installed: 21.2.0]
    - cffi [required: >=1.0.1, installed: 1.15.1]
      - pycparser [required: Any, installed: 2.21]
bokeh==2.4.2
  - Jinja2 [required: >=2.9, installed: 3.1.2]
    - MarkupSafe [required: >=2.0, installed: 2.1.1]
  - numpy [required: >=1.11.3, installed: 1.22.3]
  - packaging [required: >=16.8, installed: 23.0]
  - pillow [required: >=7.1.0, installed: 9.1.0]
  - PyYAML [required: >=3.10, installed: 6.0]
  - tornado [required: >=5.1, installed: 6.1]
  - typing-extensions [required: >=3.10.0, installed: 4.2.0]
bs4==0.0.1
  - beautifulsoup4 [required: Any, installed: 4.11.1]
    - soupsieve [required: >1.2, installed: 2.3.2.post1]
jwt==1.3.1
  - cryptography [required: !=3.4.0,>=3.1, installed: 40.0.1]
    - cffi [required: >=1.12, installed: 1.15.1]
      - pycparser [required: Any, installed: 2.21]
motor==3.0.0
  - pymongo [required: >=4.1,<5, installed: 4.3.3]
    - dnspython [required: <3.0.0,>=1.16.0, installed: 2.3.0]
nltk==3.7
  - click [required: Any, installed: 8.1.3]
  - joblib [required: Any, installed: 1.1.0]
  - regex [required: >=2021.8.3, installed: 2022.4.24]
  - tqdm [required: Any, installed: 4.64.0]
openpyxl==3.0.10
  - et-xmlfile [required: Any, installed: 1.1.0]
pkg-resources==0.0.0
requests==2.28.2
  - certifi [required: >=2017.4.17, installed: 2022.12.7]
  - charset-normalizer [required: >=2,<4, installed: 2.0.12]
  - idna [required: <4,>=2.5, installed: 3.3]
  - urllib3 [required: <1.27,>=1.21.1, installed: 1.26.15]
seaborn==0.11.2
  - matplotlib [required: >=2.2, installed: 3.5.2]
    - cycler [required: >=0.10, installed: 0.11.0]
    - fonttools [required: >=4.22.0, installed: 4.33.3]
    - kiwisolver [required: >=1.0.1, installed: 1.4.2]
    - numpy [required: >=1.17, installed: 1.22.3]
    - packaging [required: >=20.0, installed: 23.0]
    - pillow [required: >=6.2.0, installed: 9.1.0]
    - pyparsing [required: >=2.2.1, installed: 3.0.8]
    - python-dateutil [required: >=2.7, installed: 2.8.2]
      - six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.16.0]
  - numpy [required: >=1.15, installed: 1.22.3]
  - pandas [required: >=0.23, installed: 1.4.2]
    - numpy [required: >=1.18.5, installed: 1.22.3]
    - python-dateutil [required: >=2.8.1, installed: 2.8.2]
      - six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.16.0]
    - pytz [required: >=2020.1, installed: 2022.1]
  - scipy [required: >=1.0, installed: 1.8.0]
    - numpy [required: <1.25.0,>=1.17.3, installed: 1.22.3]
sklearn==0.0
  - scikit-learn [required: Any, installed: 1.0.2]
    - joblib [required: >=0.11, installed: 1.1.0]
    - numpy [required: >=1.14.6, installed: 1.22.3]
    - scipy [required: >=1.1.0, installed: 1.8.0]
      - numpy [required: <1.25.0,>=1.17.3, installed: 1.22.3]
    - threadpoolctl [required: >=2.0.0, installed: 3.1.0]
XlsxWriter==3.0.3
```

I manually update the Pipfile to match the package versions he sent (changing jwt, argon2-cffi, and requests to hardcoded version numbers). I believe I clear the vm by doing `pipenv --rm`, then do `pipenv install`. I get the same error again.

**How can I resolve a pipenv dependency issue when apparently no packages have dependency issues?** Alternatively, are there dependency issues I'm just not seeing somehow?

```
python --version
Python 3.11.3
pipenv --version
pipenv, version 2023.7.23
```

Comment: 1. You shouldn't use bs4 in your deps, but beautifulsoup4. bs4 is reserved on pypi by beautifulsoup4's owner so it installs beautifulsoup4, but it doesn't pin the version (as you can see in graph, it's "any" version). 2. What is your operating system, what is you colleague's operating system? And python version for your colleague. The problem could be with libs that don't offer source and don't have pre-built wheels for your system+python combination

Comment: I'll try dropping bs4. He says he's on WSL Ubuntu (waiting to hear back on actual version), on Python 3.8.10. The python version in the project directory is `3.9.13` which makes me realize, I thought `pipenv` also handles python versioning, apparently not, so I'll experiment with using a virtual environment with a different python version as well.

Comment: He's on 20.04 for ubuntu

Comment: Oh, and I'm on Manjaro 7.3

Comment: I removed BS4 from the pipfile, deleted Pipfile.lock, did `pipenv --rm`, confirmed there was no virtual environment with `pipenv graph`, then tried `pipenv install` again. I got the same error, and `pipenv graph` is again empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that my coworker and I were using different python versions. This was further confused by the fact that he wasn't using the python version defined in the `.python-version` file, and that apparently pipenv doesn't use the `.python-version` file but instead the `python_version` property of the `[requires]` block of the `Pipfile`. The solution was to change the following part of the Pipfile:

```
[requires]
python_version = "*"
```

To explicitly define the python version he said he was using locally:

```
[requires]
python_version = "3.8.10"
```

Then, I had to clear my pyenv virtual environment with `pipenv --rm`, then reinitialize and install packages with `pipenv install`. Upon doing so, pipenv detected the python version and installed it. This operation finally completed successfully, and when I entered the virtual environment with `pipenv shell`, I could confirm I was using python version 3.8.10 with `python --version`. Furthermore, the application ran correctly within the virtual environment.